# Drawing face colors with array glDrawElements OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I use Blender with `.obj` and `.mtl` export files for android OpenGL ES 2.0

Below image describe what i want to draw with vertices,and faces..

[image: blender screenshot]

```
ObjParse obje = new ObjParse(context,R.raw.sample_obj,R.raw.sample_mtl);
float[] koordinates = obje.getVertexKoordinates();
byte[] indicies = obje.getIndicies();
float[] colors = obje.getColors();
```

This codes bring me some array data for drawing.
And i made `FLoatBuffer` and `ByteBuffer` this arrays..

```
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(position, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, stride,floatBufKoor);
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(position);
GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(color, 4, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, stride, floatBufColors);
GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(color);

GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES,cizilecek,GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,byteBufIndicies);
```

Finally i get gradient colors,but i want solid color per faces..
How can i do this?

**EDIT:**

When i compile app i get this screenshot:

[image: android screenshot]

Comment: What does your screenshot have to do with the question? Those are flat shaded, pretty much exactly what you say you want. The .obj format allows you to have discrete colors per-vertex too. `v3` may be shared among all of those shapes, but it will have 3 different colors for 1 position, it is possible you simply are not parsing the file correctly.

Comment: It all depends on the shader you are using, if you are using illumination. About gradient, what do you mean? Could you please share a screenshot of the result you are getting?

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman parsing `.obj` file i get a float which produced by `.mtl` file only shadeless color info.how can i parse for individual faced color?

Comment: @MaurizioBenedetti i edited and added screenshot to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *is* a limited way to color the faces of your glDrawElements mesh by triangle (as shown in Blender) instead of by vertex (as shown in the lower image):

1. Pass the position attribute as a vec4 instead of vec3, use a stride of 4 for float[] koordinates.
2. Set the fourth (w) value of each vertex to a "dictionary" value corresponding to each color. E.g. 0.0f = yellow, 0.5f = red, 1.0f = white. *The middle value will be the "default."*
3. In the vertex shader, pass the w value to the frag shader as a varying, then reset the w to 1.0 before performing matrix transformations like perspective etc. *Use < or > 0.5f due to interpolation.*
4. In the fragment shader, compare the varying to fixed values and set fragment color to predefined values before performing shading adjustments.

You can use a little more creativity (binary masks?) to index more colors but each strategy is limited to using a single w for the color (without being able to use a mat3 as an attribute in glDrawElements in ES2.0). You can also pass float[] colors (only one entry per color) as a uniform vec3 array and read color values from there.